# Which type of cooker to use above 6000m?

Tags: gear, mountaineering, stoves

I'm an enthusiastic mountaineer and hiked up several 4000m - 6000m peaks till today. Now I'm faced to a problem I think many mountaineers are faced to:

Which type of cooker do I use above the 6000m?

Normally I use my oldest friend the propan-fired cooker. But the cold temperatures told me about the physics and around -30°C it won't fire at all.
That's why I thought about a gas-fired cooker, but it's also heavier and often bigger ...

So does anybody have some experience in cooking above 6000m?